# Ionic 3 Local Notifications Permissions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, localnotification, ionic-native

Could you tell me how to ask Permissions upfront?
I'm using [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin.

I have tried below code.But no luck?

```
 changePaymentReminders() {
    if (this.data.isEnabledPaymentReminders) this.localNotifications.registerPermission();
  }
```

I need to show this dialog. It works with the notification. But I need to ask it from the user in advance.

[image]